# Typesetting quotients and double quotients

Tags: math-mode

What is the best way to typeset mathematical quotients and double quotients?

I mean constructions like `X/~` (~ an equivalence relation on X) and `G\X/H` (where G and H are groups acting on X).  While the simple case is solved by something like `X/\mathord\sim` (or maybe with `\mathbin/`), this gets hard to parse for the reader in more complicated situations and with double quotients. An alternative is a slanted `\sfrac{X}{\mathord\sim}` (from `xfrac`), but that makes the X rather small and doesn't work for double quotients.

Do you have better ideas?

Comment: Could you add an example of a more compicated situation?

Comment: Maybe this is (partly) answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4624/1235)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that TeX's spacing table is missing a class for `/` and `\` which are binary operators without any spacing before and after. As it's not possible to add spacing classes like `\mathrel`, `\mathbin` (I hope it will be possible one day with LuaTeX), there is no perfect solution for this problem.

One way to emulate this spacing class is to use `\mathclose{}/\mathopen{}`, but this will not work with `\big`, `\middle`, etc. In order to get around this problem, you need to use the TeX primitive `\delimiter` (the LaTeX equivalent `\DeclareMathDelimiter` won't do here because it doesn't allow to add code after it). For the slash, it is `\delimiter"502F30E`. The `"` indicates it's a hex number, the `5` that it is of type `\mathclose`, the `02F` that the non extensible variant of the delimiter is in position `2F` in the math font number `0` (that's the `operators` font which is used for `\sin`, etc.), the `30E` that the extensible version of the delimiter is in position `0E` in the math font number `3` (that's the font containing extensible symbols). So by using `\delimiter"502F30E\mathopen{}`, we would have something which has the correct spacing and works well with `\left`, `\right`, etc.

There are two choices now: either you define a macro containing this definition (which is the natural solution for `\backslash`) or you want just to type `/` and still get the correct spacing. For the first solution, you could use any macro, but if you want to use `\slash` and keep the original definition of `\slash` in text mode, you could use something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@old@slash}{}\let\@old@slash\slash
\def\slash{\relax\ifmmode\delimiter"502F30E\mathopen{}\else\@old@slash\fi}
\makeatother

\def\backslash{\delimiter"526E30F\mathopen{}}

\begin{document}

$E\slash\sim$ $\left.E\middle\slash\sim\right.$

$H\backslash G\slash K$ $\left.H\middle\backslash G\middle\slash K\right.$

\end{document}
```

If you prefer the second solution, you must make `/` active in math mode (in text mode, it will remain normal). It's a bit tricky if you want it to work well with babel packages which also mess with active characters. The following is adapted from code used by the [magyar language babel module](http://www.math.bme.hu/latex/magyar_pre_tug2004.pdf#page=28) for their factorial:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Define \addto if it doesn't exists

\@ifundefined{addto}{\def\addto#1#2{%
  \ifx#1\@undefined
    \def#1{#2}%
  \else
    \ifx#1\relax
      \def#1{#2}%
    \else
      {\toks@\expandafter{#1#2}%
        \xdef#1{\the\toks@}}%
    \fi
  \fi
}}{}

% Command to add commands "at every math formula" which
% takes into account the package nath.
% Adapted from:
%   http://www.math.bme.hu/latex/magyar_pre_tug2004.pdf#page=28

\def\addto@every@math{%
  \expandafter\addto\csname \expandafter\ifx
  \csname mathoptions@on\endcsname\relax % detect nath.sty
  check@mathfonts\else mathoptions@on\fi\endcsname
}

% Command to define a single character even when it is not active
% with a lowercase trick

\def\active@def#1{%
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`#1\relax\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}%
}

% Command to change the definition of #1 into #2 ; beware of cyclic
% behaviours when using this to redefine characters like !, :, or ;
% Adapted from:
%   http://www.math.bme.hu/latex/magyar_pre_tug2004.pdf#page=28

\def\fixmathspacing#1#2{%
  \addto@every@math{%
    \catcode`#1=12 \mathcode`#1="8000
    \active@def#1{#2}%
  }%
}

\makeatother %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\fixmathspacing{/}{\mathclose{}\mathchar"013D\mathopen{}}

\def\backslash{\delimiter"526E30F\mathopen{}}

\begin{document}

$E/\sim$ $\left.E\middle/\sim\right.$

$H\backslash G/ K$ $\left.H\middle\backslash G\middle/ K\right.$

\end{document}
```

The macro `\fixmathspacing` should work with any math character you want (semi-colon, etc.), just beware of cyclic redefinitions as mentioned in the comments of the code (using `\delimiter` or `\mathchar` is safe).

One last thing: if you want to specify the height of the slash or backslash, neither `\big` nor `\bigm` will produce the right spacing (unlike `\middle`) so you should probably also define a new `\big` variant, called for example `\bign` (`n` standing for `no space`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\bign#1{\mathclose{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to8.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}\mathopen{}}
\def\Bign#1{\mathclose{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to11.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}\mathopen{}}
\def\biggn#1{\mathclose{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to14.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}\mathopen{}}
\def\Biggn#1{\mathclose{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to17.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}\mathopen{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{lccccl}
\verb"\big" & $E\big/\sim$ & $E\Big/\sim$ & $E\bigg/\sim$ & $E\Bigg/\sim$ & too much space after \\
\verb"\bigm" & $E\bigm/\sim$ & $E\Bigm/\sim$ & $E\biggm/\sim$ & $E\Biggm/\sim$& too much space before \\
\verb"\bign" & $E\bign/\sim$ & $E\Bign/\sim$ & $E\biggn/\sim$ & $E\Biggn/\sim$ & correct spacing \\
\end{tabular}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks good. I'll accept your answer once I had some time to play around with it.

Comment: Just a small observation: `\backslash` and `/` are of type Ord, not Bin. The spacing in your first example comes actually from the fact that `\sim` is of type Rel.

Comment: @morbusg: syntactically, `\backslash` and `/` are binary operators, but, as their spacing is special, they cannot be of type `\mathbin`. The choice of `\mathord` for them was probably not the best as putting `/` of type `\mathopen` and `\backslash` of type `\mathclose` prevents the most obvious problems like `E/\sim`, `E/\ker f`, `n/\ln n` and `\sim\backslash E` and requires no hacks.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet: I guess you mean ‘So by using `\delimiter"502F30E\mathopen{}`’ at the end of the second paragraph, don’t you?

Comment: @mhp: yes, it should be `\mathopen`. I've edited the answer to correct it.

Answer (score 29):

The simplest way to write the tilde is to wrap `\sim` in braces (so the quotient set is denoted `X/{\sim}`). This stops TeX from treating `\sim` as a binary operator, so the tilde is spaced correctly.

Source: http://pbelmans.wordpress.com/2010/11/16/caveat-correct-spacing-in-quotient/