# On using the slash to denote division in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In in-line math mode, I tend to use the literal slash (i.e. `/`) to denote division. Unlike the common binary operators [`+ - \times \div`], `/` is treated as an ordinary math object, though. This may easily result in inconsistent (asymmetric) horizontal spacing, for instance when `/` is preceded by a variable and succeeded by a function, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\(\tan x = \sin x / \cos x\)

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Of course, I can correct the horizontal spacing by turning `\cos x` into an ordinary math object:

```
\(\tan x = \sin x / {\cos x}\)
```

Output:

[image]

Alternatively, I can make `/` function as a binary operator similar to [`+ - \times \div`]:

```
\(\tan x = \sin x \mathbin{/} \cos x\)
```

Output:

[image]

Now, I am curious: Which of the above two workarounds should be preferred? Or is there even a better one?

Comment: my preference would be to treat it as a binary operator.

Comment: Knuth decided _not_ to have `/` behave as a binary operator, following printer's traditions ("printer" as in "someone who operates a printing press".) (I guess that's well known to you, @barbarabeeton.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt: OK, this means you’d use the first workaround?

Comment: @mhp: Yes indeed! But you made a very interesting observation in your question! Somehow it would be nice if `/` would be clever enough to behave in the correct way automatically if followed by a mathop.

Comment: @mhp In chapter 18 of the TeXbook, `$n/\!\log n$` is recommended. Doing this is equivalent to `$n/{\log n}$, but I'd prefer using `\!`.

Comment: @HendrikVogt -- er, umm, indeed.  what you say is true.  but it's also true that the space on either side of the slash should be uniform.  i've done a little research in the books on math typesetting that i have on my shelf, and the spaces in pre-tex examples were almost always visually equal in width.  i found one tex example (not in the texbook; thanks @egreg) with a slash followed by `\log` and there the wider space on the right was camouflaged by the height of the `l`.  maybe this is a topic for a disquisition on "niceties"; i'll pursue that.

Comment: @barbara: Yes, of course - the spaces should be uniform. And knowing too little TeX has indeed let to some cases of poor typesetting in books nowadays. Fortunately, the above typographical error occurs less often than the `$|\sin x|$` spacing error.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: One could make the slash an opening symbol using ``\mathcode`\/="402F``. But I’m not sure whether this is a good idea …

Comment: @mhp: That would be _mostly_ very good, but `\left(...\right)/\left(...\right)` would come out badly.

Comment: @mhp: this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7075/typesetting-quotients-and-double-quotients Making the slash of open class is indeed a possible quick fix (but not a perfect one). More complex methods are needed to adress the issue completely.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should definitely prefer the version `\sin x / {\cos x}` with the small spaces, or `\sin x / \!\cos x` as egreg suggests. From the TeXbook, page 132:

> TeX does not treat `/` as a binary operation, even though a slash stands for division (which qualifies as a binary operation on mathematical grounds). The reason is that printers traditionally put extra space around the symbols `+`, `−`, and `*`, but not around `/`.

Knuth continues, explaining that `1 \mathbin{/} 2` would come out

[image: one half]

> which is wrong; so TeX considers `/` to be an ordinary symbol.

And from page 170:

> In the formula `$n/\log n$`, TeX automatically inserts an unwanted thin space before `\log`, since the slash is treated as an ordinary symbol, and since a thin space is usually desirable between an ordinary symbol and an operator like `\log`.

Comment: This only explains why `/` is treated differently by TeX, not why one shouldn't treat it as a binary operator oneself. IMHO “tradition” is not a very strong argument if it is one at all… (BTW: I don't actually have an opinion whether `/` should be a binary operator or not…)

Comment: @cgnieder: "Tradition" often is not a strong argument, true, but I do respect _printers_ traditions a lot. See also my edit.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: I do respect printers' tradition very much, too! But I find the picture much more convincing!

Comment: @cgnieder: That's what I hoped for `:-)` Thanks for inducing me to add the picture!

Answer (score 10):

In your case you use `/` as binary operator: `\mathbin{/}`:

```
$a \mathbin{/} b$
```

As an abbreviation a command could be defined to act as slash as binary operator:

```
\mathchardef\mslash="202F
$a \mslash b$
```

Or the symbol `/` can be changed globally to act as binary operator:

```
\mathcode`\/="202F
$a / b$
```

The starting number is the class, 0x200 is binary operator. The last two digits
of the hexadecimal number `2F` is the character code of `/`.

Comment: Typographically I wouldn't recommend doing that, see my comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are three LaTeX packages that seem to help: [xfrac](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xfrac), [nicefrac](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac) and (possibly) [faktor](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/faktor) (which last I have never looked at; there is a reference to it in the catalogue entry for nicefrac). Note that xfrac is a LaTeX-3-coded package.

It is possible that none of those help, but I would sooner use a tried-and-tested package than twiddle with the inner workings of maths mode (which generally makes me feel slightly ill).

Comment: It would be great if you can give the snapshots of the output with simple examples.

Comment: As far as I know the `xfrac` package can’t help in this context. But I suspect it theoretically could.